# Document Library Custom Form

Tags: document-library, custom-form

I have a document library where i have added a custom edit form. I also have given a custom dropdownlist in that form for the user to select the Content Type and default sharepoint save/back buttons. What i'm trying to achieve is a default workflow for all documents in a library. When i fill and save my form, document isnt forwarded to 'approved documents' section.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="menu">
    <table>
        <SharePoint:ChangeContentType ID="contentType" runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"  />
        <SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ID="lfi" runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"  />
    </table>
    <wssuc:Toolbar ID="Toolbar1" runat="server" ButtonSeparator="&nbsp">
    <Template_RightButtons>              
       <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ID="SaveBtn" />
       <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ID="CancelBtn" />
    </Template_RightButtons>
    </wssuc:Toolbar>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <embed id="test" src=""  min-width="650px" width="100%" height="600px" style="border: none;" runat="server" />

</div>
```

Im pretty sure theres a problem with these buttons but ive got no idea how to maintain default doc library workflow without them.

Any help would be really appreciated :)